# Why wouldn't Java Map work? The function .put() not inserting the value and only inserting the key

Tags: java

When I try to insert a value relating to its key the value is not inserting inside the map. It seems like the "ids" doesn't have any value in it but it does.

```
    Map<String, Vector<String>> graph = new HashMap<String, Vector<String>>();
    ArrayList<String[]> words = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    Vector<String> ids = new Vector<String>();
    String[] id = null;
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(fInName));
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
       words.add(scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+"));
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        id = words.get(i)[1].split("[,]", 0);
        for(int j = 0; j < id.length; j++) {
            ids.add(j, id[j]);
        }
        graph.put(words.get(i)[0], ids);
        id = null;
        ids.clear();            
    }
    
    for (Map.Entry<String, Vector<String>> entry : graph.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() +
                         ", Value = " + entry.getValue());

    }
```

Comment: It's inserting just fine, but you're clearing the vector. What do you think `ids.clear()` does?

Comment: I want remove all the elements after I have put it inside graph so I can add new words and values . Should I use a different function?

Comment: If you clear the vector, the vector is going to be empty. It doesn't matter if you clear it before or after putting it in the dictionary. If you don't want it to be cleared, then make a new vector (`new Vector<String>()`)

Comment: You need a `new Vector<>()` is what you need, not clearing the original Vector.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much guys.

Comment: In case if this is not clear, Java passes objects by reference, so you were clearing the same vector that you have just added. Map does not have a copy, but the same object. Thus all the changes are reflected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The put() function works by reference.  So

```
put (key, ids)
```

stores a reference (memory pointer) to the same ids object that you are running the clear() function on.  Trying to 'clean up' your memory is laudable, but in this case you're shooting your own foot.  What you want is something like this

```
Map<String, Vector<String>> graph = new HashMap<String, Vector<String>>();
ArrayList<String[]> words = new ArrayList<String[]>();
Vector<String> ids;
String[] id = null;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(fInName));
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   words.add(scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+"));
}

for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
    id = words.get(i)[1].split("[,]", 0);
    ids = new Vector<String>();
    for(int j = 0; j < id.length; j++) {
        ids.add(j, id[j]);
    }
    graph.put(words.get(i)[0], ids);        
}
```